Raviart--Thomas space in tensor context, does it exist? (mixed finite element method)
The Raviart--Thomas space is defined as
$RT_m(T)=\mathbb{P}_m(T)^n+x\,\mathbb{P}_m(T)$
where $\mathbb{P}_m(T)$ is the polynomial space with degree less than $m$, and $n=2$ or $n=3$. Here $T$ is a triangle (in 2D) or tetrahedron (in 3D), corresponding to an element of a mesh of a domain $\Omega$ (typical in finite element context).
These space has good properties to approximate the solution of some problems where the unknown belong to $H(\text{div},\Omega)=\{v\in L^2(\Omega)^n:\text{div}(v)\in L^2(\Omega)\}$ (mixed finite element methods).
For this, a reference book is Theory and Practice of Finite Elements of Ern and Guermond.
But, in some applications, we have a tensor $\sigma$ belonging to $\mathbb{H}(\text{div},\Omega)$, where $\mathbb{H}(\text{div})$ is the space of elements in $L^2(\Omega)^{n\times n}$ such that each row belongs to $H(\text{div},\Omega)$.
Do you know some book or article with the properties of $\mathbb{H}(\text{div},\Omega)$? Or they do not exists?
